# Get Min and Max of a Range Without Stats Agg or Duplicate Aggs Error?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I feel stuck trying to get the pipeline aggregation to do what I want in practice.
I will post what I have, but the idea:

1. Make a date range and make buckets for each month for the last 10 months in that range. Got it.
2. Get the Min and Max of each bucket's "magnitude" field. I can only figure out how to do that with "stats" agg because I get duplicate error if I try to do both as separate aggs. Yet, I do not want the other stats. Can I avoid the stats agg to this?
3. Sum the scores. How in the world do I do that? That is kicking my tail. I do not know if you can sum the _score field.

So here is the index I made up to practice based on the common earthquakes concept to practice on:

```
PUT _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "date": "30-09-2020", "magnitude": "3.4", "lon": "74.12", "lat": "43.67" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "date": "30-09-2020", "magnitude": "1.2", "lon": "78.02", "lat": "103.07" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "date": "15-10-2020", "magnitude": "2.5", "lon": "178.02", "lat": "98.41" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "date": "19-11-2020", "magnitude": "1.9", "lon": "14.67", "lat": "100.35" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "5" } }
{ "date": "13-12-2020", "magnitude": "6.2", "lon": "123.93", "lat": "56.05" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "6" } }
{ "date": "21-12-2020", "magnitude": "0.2", "lon": "130.31", "lat": "83.41" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "7" } }
{ "date": "17-01-2021", "magnitude": "0.2", "lon": "10.31", "lat": "98.00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "8" } }
{ "date": "23-01-2021", "magnitude": "4.6", "lon": "112.31", "lat": "69.96" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "9" } }
{ "date": "31-01-2021", "magnitude": "0.4", "lon": "79.43", "lat": "72.14" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "earthquakes", "_id" : "10" } }
{ "date": "03-02-2021", "magnitude": "7.1", "lon": "120.80", "lat": "50.22" }
```

Here is what I put together for the aggregation. Note: I had put the hits at 10 before trying to sum the _score field...which did not happen:

```
GET earthquakes/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "range_mag": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "date",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "now-10M",
            "to": "now"
                }
              ]
            },
            "aggs": {
              "by_month_mag": {
                "date_histogram": {
                  "field": "date",
                  "calendar_interval": "month"
                },
                "aggs": {
                  "stat_mag": {
                    "stats": {
                      "field": "magnitude"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

^ That works but to get min and max, but adds in data I do not need. I didn't put my sum of the score because it was driving me nuts. Is there a better way to get after what I am trying to do?
Anyway, thanks. Out of all the things I can type away with ease or work through with the documentation, aggregations are just the one thing I thought I'd get but somehow feel stuck on.

Comment: the question is almost perfectly made , you missed the mappings. This ones are working for me PUT earthquakes
{
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format": "dd-MM-yyyy"
        },
        "lat" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "lon" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "magnitude" : {
          "type" : "double"
        }
      }
    }
}

Comment: Added an answer, With scores sum do you mean to literally sum the scores of all the results? Just for curiosity: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Just added the aggregation to sume the scores. Please remember to mark the answer as correct if it was useful or let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: llermaly, I failed to mention that I made explicit mappings in an index template to practice index templates and mappings for this. Thank you for reminding that I need to be more mindful of putting all details.
Yes, I did mean the sum of the scores for all results. Why? Because it was a task I failed at figuring out. Simple as that. I think I have been studying too hard if that is possible. I am starting to miss the simple things like summing on "script" and not "field". Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Most of questions have no example data, no mappings and/or no queries , so this was a 9/10. Glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For min/max you can do separate aggs of the same field, and to sum the scores you do

```
    "score_sum":{
      "sum": {
        "script": "_score"
      }
    }
```

**Final Query**

```
GET earthquakes/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "score_sum": {
      "sum": {
        "script": "_score"
      }
    },
    "range_mag": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "date",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "now-10M",
            "to": "now"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_month_mag": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "date",
            "calendar_interval": "month"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "min_mag": {
              "min": {
                "field": "magnitude"
              }
            },
            "max_mag": {
              "max": {
                "field": "magnitude"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You know, I need that palm to face emote right now. I have been pounding away moving the aggs around trying to make that happen with constant "duplicate aggregation" errors trying to employ the min max separately. And "script"...how did I miss that?! Out of everything in elasticsearch, this one the one thing that I have not had the light bulb come on until now. All it took was course correction in a simple way.
That nailed the task that has been bugging me perfectly. Weight lifted. Thank you!

Comment: So what I realized I had been doing wrong after look at it again was the last agg, the "max_mag" I had been doing like this:
````
"aggs": {
            "min_mag": {
              "min": {
                "field": "magnitude"
              }
            },
            "aggs"
            "max_mag": {
              "max": {
                "field": "magnitude"
````
I had also tried jumping out of that agg into a completely new one by placing the comma one closed-bracket down and got the duplicate-error. Light bulb is on. Thanks again.